# Identifying devices on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

My Linux box has three devices, sda, sda1 and sda2. How can I find out what each one of these are? I'm running Ubuntu 9.04.

Answer (score 6):

sda is the first SATA/SAS/SCSI HDD in the computer. sda1 is the first partition on that disk, sda2 is the second. sudo fdisk -l should show you the info you want.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say that if that's the only hard drive in your box, then sda1 is your root partition and sdb2 is swap.

Comment: I've wondered about this too -- so how do you know which storage device is the first? What do you mean by first?

Comment: First as detected by the BIOS. Usually its the drive plugged into SATA 0 in a standard desktop. In a server it's the drive attached to bay 0.

Comment: Emmeff - If there is only 2 it is probably /boot and a LVM. Usually the default config will provide 3 partitions minimum. One for /boot, one for swap and one for /. So it wouldn't surprise me to find /boot and a LVM with / and swap on it.

Comment: Don't forget the sudo.

Comment: Good call. Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

[GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) is a great utility that will tell you graphically what all your hard drives and partitions are.

Comment: I use GParted whenever I have a GUI on a system, otherwise, I'll then have to use the obscure CLI stuff I need a gui browser just to look up how to use them right!

Answer (score 2):

sda originally referred to a **S**CSI **d**isk, **a** being the first drive. There could be sdb, sdc and so on. Now it can refer to SATA or SAS as well as previously mentioned.

- sda1 - first partition on sda, bootloader/kernel usually.
- sda2 - second partition, usually swap
- sda3 - third partition, usually root fs.

That used to be the traditional setup at least if you were using a SATA/SCSI/SAS drive. If it shows up as hda, that means your disk is connected via IDE rather than one of the previously mentioned methods.

Comment: In SATA/SAS there is no master or slave each drive has its own channel. For SCSI it is determined by the device ID as there is no master/slave there either.

Comment: whoops